# How Do I prevent the login page defaulting to the except part of the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am stuck with this login form, when the user logs into the webpage, the information is pulled from the database, verified if the username and password hash is correct against that username, if a match is present the user should be logged in.

This is not the case for me as when correct credentials are supplied, the user is not logged in and it states the credentials are invalid. As well as when the page is first loaded, it will display "invalid credentials, try again1" in the error variable.

I have tried basically placing what the user would submit in the password field however it doesn't appear to work, as following the documentation, supplying a plain text password myself works without any problems is there something else that is wrong? Or is it simply an indentation issue?

*EDIT* After a little more messing around it turns out the except part is always activated on a GET request when the hyperlink is clicked, I would not have thought this would be a thing that will automatically jump to the exception part of the code.

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, request, session, g, flash, redirect, url_for
import time
import random
from contextlib import closing
#import hashlib, binascii
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256, argon2
from argon2 import PasswordHasher

app = Flask(__name__) # creates applications instance
app.config.from_object(__name__) # loads configuration from this file, flaskr.py

# loads default config, overrides config from an enviroment variable
app.config.update(dict(
DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),
SECRET_KEY='DEVELIPMENT KEY', # required to keep client-side session secure
    USERNAME='ADMININSTRATOR_ACCOUNT_ThAT_THIS_METHOD_SHOULD_NOT_BE_USED',
PASSWORD='DEFAULT*aG1'
))
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)


# may need SQLite3.Row
def connect_db():
# Connects to specific database in this case SQLite3
rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
return rv

# initilises database, closing() helper function keeps connection open
def init_db():
with closing(connect_db()) as db:
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

#def init_db():
#db = get_db()
# open_resouce() method of app object is helper function that opens resouce that app provides
#opens the file from resource location flaskr/flaskr folder and allows you to read from it, used to execute script on db connection
#with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
    #db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
#db.commit()

# called before request is made, passes no arguments, db connection is stored on g object
@app.before_request
def before_request():
g.db = connect_db()


# When the command executes, Flask will automatically create an application context which is bound to the right application. Within the function, you can then access flask.g and other things as you might expect. When the script ends, the application context tears down and the database connection is released
@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
"""Initializes the database."""
init_db()
print('Initialized the database.')

DATABASE = '/flaskr.db'

def get_db():
"""Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
current application context.
"""
if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
    g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
"""Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
    g.sqlite_db.close()


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
error = ''
try:
    db = get_db()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        requesteddatafromdb = db.execute("SELECT * FROM userssignedup WHERE firstname = (%s) and password = (%s)",
                   thwart(request.form['username'] and request.form['password']))

        requesteddatafromdb = getdataindb.fetchone()[2]


        passhasher = PasswordHasher()
        hashp = passhasher.hash("request.form['password']")
        print(hashp)
        if passhasher.verify(hashp, "request.form['password']"):
            session['logged_in'] = True
            session['username'] = request.form['username']

            flash('You were logged in')
        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
    else:
        error = "incorrect credentials....."
    gc.collect()

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

except Exception as e:
    #flash (e)
    error = "invalid credentials, try again1"
return render_template('login1.html', error=error)
```